# Change Background colour of ListView in android at run time

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I am doing project in **Android**. I want to change `background` color as well as `textcolor` of selected item from ***ListView***. Here is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="265dp"
            android:layout_height="366dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.00"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" >

        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

So,I have `ListView` with some student names and with facility of multiple choice by using `checkbox`.

```
ListView stud_lst=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

stud_lst.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```

I want to change the background and text color of selected student. 
I already saw some answers but I am not getting it.
Please help me.

Comment: make the custom row for listview.onclick change the background color and text color of the custom row.

Comment: Any other idea without using custom row

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom adapter and in your activity class do the following:

```
   //  mListview is ur listview object.
   mListview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
                    view.setBackgroundColor("your bg's color id");
            }
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to create a Custom Adapter to change the item's Background Color. Here is the example of Custom adapter:

```
public class PaListAdapter  extends BaseAdapter{
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

         private ArrayList<String> platevalue = new ArrayList<String>();

           ViewHolder holder;
        public PaListAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<String> value)
        {
            // Cache the LayoutInflate to avoid asking for a new one each time.
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);



            //mycontext = context;
            platevalue.clear();
            platevalue =value;



        }


        public int getCount() 
        {
            return platevalue.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) 
        {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) 
        {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
        {





            if (convertView == null) 
            {
                 convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.select_dialog, null);

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.hTransID =(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtChoice);




                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }
            else 
            {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.hTransID.setText(platevalue.get(position));




            return convertView;
        }

        static class ViewHolder 
        {      
              TextView    hTransID;


        }
    }
```

select_dialog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
 android:background="#000000"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtChoice"

        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:textColor="#000000"/> 

</LinearLayout>
```

In Activity Class.Define it like:

```
simpleefficientadapter efficientadapter;

  efficientadapter=new simpleefficientadapter(CLASSNAME.this, VALUES);
   listView.setAdapter(efficientadapter);
```